# Erro com socket tcp em android

Tags: java, android

Estou tendo um erro null, já não sei mais o que faço, estou usando socket tcp em java no android studio, já adcionei a permissão no manifest, antes dava errado de permission denied, agora já da erro nulo, e tipo eu fiz esse mesmo código só que usando terminal, e deu certo, só com o android studio q da errado

o codigo é essa aqui

```
tn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Socket client;
            try {
                client = new Socket("10.0.1.138", 2000);
                while (true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enviado para 10.0.1.138", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    client.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Como esta o manifest na parte de network?

Comment: Agora deve estar dando erro de operação de rede no thread principal. Teria que fazer num thread em background.

Comment: Amigos, eu acabei perdendo o codigo que eu estava fazendo, tive que fazer uma formatação no meu hd, agradeço a ajuda de vocês, mas acho que não era erro de thread, já que antes eu fiz em java puro um codigo igual só que em console, acredito que seria alguma restrição do proprio android